# Под картинкой инпут радио, стилизация активности

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<input id="radio_ava8"  class="ava_radio"  name="1 " type="radio" value="1" />  
<label class="ava_img" for="radio_ava8">            
    <img src="/i/ava8.gif" width="100"  height="100" />
</label>

.ava_radio  {display: none;}
```

Под картинкой инпут радио, стилизация активности. Я скрыл инпут, под картинку, как сделать что бы при выборе ее появился border? Нужен сам стиль на css и что бы работала ИЕ7+ cheked работает с 9+. Может на jquery?

```
???? {
border: 1px solid #ededeed;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для достижения эффекта нужно использовать + в правилах. например:

```
.ava_radio:checked + .ava_img > img {
    border:solid 1px #ededed; 
}
```

Можно и без `> img`, но тогда придется придумывать размеры и `display` для `label`, которые не совпадают с `img`...

Соответственно, чтоб работало в ie7, в jquery можно использовать этот селектор в обработчике изменения:

```
$(".ava_radio:not(:checked) + .ava_img > img").css("border","solid 1px white");
$(".ava_radio:checked + .ava_img > img").css("border","solid 1px #ededed");
```

Comment: Вот [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/ivanovsuper/A3C7r/)

Comment: Если уж все-равно используется jquery какой смысл заморачиваться с CSS3 селекторами?

Comment: ну, например, когда появится желание похоронить старье, то этот костыль можно просто вынести в отдельный файл... и не подключать его. Это как раз тот случай когда css3 решение короче, как та самая сестра...

Comment: Что за "Обработчик изменений"? В ИЕ7 и в ИЕ8 код не работает. ЧТо может быть? Вставил код из второго примера

Comment: не имею под рукой ie7,8 дебажить надо... сорри.

Answer (score 1):

```
#radio_ava8:checked {
   border: 1px solid #ededeed;
}
```

UPD: А, стоп, вам же надо бордер задать не инпуту, а картинке? Тогда не подойдет. Что-то мне подсказывает, что средствами CSS  тут не обойдетесь, нужен будет яваскрипт для манипуляции стилями. Хотя, возможно, кто-то подскажет замечательный вариант на CSS.